# trying to add a variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm on day one of Ruby and I can't do the most basic of things. The code below is a sample of what I am trying to do. I simply need to add the user input wit the variable. I keep getting a "can't convert float into string" error message.

The more I research a solution, the more it steers me in a different direction. Recasting variables should be pretty simple. I don't understand what i'm doing wrong.

```
var1 = Float("9.99")

puts "enter in your quantity"

quantity1 = gets + var1

puts "quantity1"
```

Answer (score 1):

`gets` returns a string, so you need to cast it to something `Numeric` in order to add a float to it.

`quantity = gets.to_f + var1`

will work, but I suggest that you'll do some more reading.

Also you can assign `var1` like this: `var1 = 9.99`

Comment: Oh i see what I did. My puts had qutoes around quantity

Comment: I did actually recast using the to_f fn. I do need to do more reading.

Answer (score 1):

`gets` stands for get string. You need to convert that string to an integer or a float using the method `.to_i` (to integer) or `.to_f` (to float).

I would do this:

`var1 = 9.99
puts "enter in your quantity"
quantity1 = gets.to_f + var1
puts quantity1`

Note you don't have to specify when a variable is "Float" if you use the decimale separator when you are declaring it. you can see this typing

`puts var1.class`

it will return `Float`